# add_filter with retrieve_password_message() not working in plugin, but works in functions.php

Tags: filters

I'm trying to use retrieve_password_message to change the lost password email. The problem is that when I use it in a theme's functions.php, it works great, but when I put it into my (activated, working properly in other ways) plugin, it doesn't work.  Does anyone know why? I have the priority set as 1.

Comment: would you supply the code chunk you're using so we can see if you're using any improper syntax or routes blocked by the API?